# Ошибка при обучении нейронной сети

Tags: python

Делал все по гайду от [хабра](https://habr.com/ru/post/506166/) при выполнения 8 пункта, вылезает ошибка. Ниже приложен скриншот и сама ошибка в текстовом виде. [image: скриншот]

```
github: skipping check (not a git repository)
```

YOLOv3  2021-6-9 torch 1.9.0+cu111 CPU

```
Namespace(weights='data/yolov3-spp.pt', cfg='data/yolov3-spp.cfg', data='data/conf.data', hyp='data/hyp.scratch.yaml', epochs=300, batch_size=4, img_size=[640, 640], rect=False, resume=False, nosave=True, notest=False, noautoanchor=False, evolve=False, bucket='', cache_images=False, image_weights=False, device='', multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, adam=False, sync_bn=False, local_rank=-1, workers=8, project='runs/train', entity=None, name='exp', exist_ok=False, quad=False, linear_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, save_period=-1, artifact_alias='latest', world_size=1, global_rank=-1, save_dir='runs\\train\\exp6', total_batch_size=4)

tensorboard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs/train', view at http://localhost:6006/

hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.2, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.5, cls_pw=1.0, obj=1.0, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0

wandb: (1) Create a W&B account

wandb: (2) Use an existing W&B account

wandb: (3) Don't visualize my results

←[34m←[1mwandb←[0m: Enter your choice:
```

Comment: Не вижу ошибки, вижу вопрос от программы